# Plant-based lamb?

Tags: substitutions, texture, lamb, seitan, plant-based

How could plant-based lamb be made? I'm looking not only to imitate the flavor* but also the texture of slow-cooked lamb.

<sup>*cf. "[How can I imitate the flavor of lamb?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/113385/42013)"</sup>

Comment: Please explain - you linked to another Q/A. Why isn’t your question a duplicate? To me it looks suspiciously so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I imitate the flavor of lamb?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113385/how-can-i-imitate-the-flavor-of-lamb)

Comment: @Stephie I'm primarily looking to imitate the texture of slow-cooked lamb.

Comment: This is one of those challenges that the food industry has been trying to crack for decades. I'm sure once they do it will be popular. At the moment 'meat-free meat' just isn't there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [seitan recipe](https://www.bobsredmill.com/vital-wheat-gluten.html):

> SEITAN This versatile vegan meat replacement can be seared, grilled or
> fried!
>
> - 1¾ cups Vital Wheat Gluten (seitan)
> - ⅓ cup Nutritional Yeast
> - 2 tsp Garlic Granules
> - 1 tsp Onion Powder
> - 2 tsp Crushed Fennel
> - ½ tsp Turmeric
> - 3 Tbsp Soy Sauce
> - 1 tsp Molasses
> - 1 tsp Tahini
> - 1½ Tbsp Oil
> - 1½ cups Mushroom or Vegetable Broth
>
> In a medium bowl, whisk wheat gluten, nutritional yeast and dry
> spices. In a separate bowl, combine remaining ingredients and stir
> until smooth. Make a well in the dry ingredients and pour in the wet
> mixture, using a fork to bring dough together (it will be lumpy and
> springy).
>
> Pour dough onto an 18-inch-long sheet of aluminum foil or parchment
> paper and wrap like a burrito, forming log.
>
> Bring 4-6 cups water to a rolling boil in a medium pot and place a
> tight-fitting steamer basket inside. Add seitan, wrapped in foil or
> parchment, cover with the pot lid and steam for 80 minutes.
> Do not remove lid. Let seitan cool for 30 minutes before cutting into
> slices or chunks. Enjoy as is or sear on the stovetop.
>
> *Makes 1 large loaf.*

Instead of nutritional yeast, add cooked TVP to modify texture. Instead of the spices suggested above, use a lamb marinade or seasoning.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdMp2EsCuTg) (or [this similar one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFYcQIlR-JQ) using cooked pasta and tofu).

Happy Easter!

---

<sup>From the [*OED* for "seitan"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdMp2EsCuTg):
**Etymology:** < Japanese *seitan* (apparently a1966 (see note); usually written in katakana; not listed in dictionaries of Japanese), probably < *sei-* raw, unprocessed, bio- (originally ‘life, birth’; < Middle Chinese) + *tan-* (in *tanpaku*, *tanpakushitsu* protein; < Middle Chinese), or perhaps < Japanese *sei-* to be, become ( < Middle Chinese) + *tan-*.
The word is said to have been coined in the early 1960s by the Japanese founder of macrobiotics, Nyoichi (or Nyoiti) Sakurazawa, known in the West as George (or Georges) Ohsawa (1893–1966).</sup>